# sql group rows by column B but only if they match in column A

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having some serious problems with this one.

```
TABLE
----------------------------------
DATE         EVENT       CATEGORY
2016-04-20   football    sport
2016-04-20   ishockey    sport
2016-04-20   whiteroom   bar
2016-04-29   football    sport
```

How can I group these so that I'll get

```
TABLE
----------------------------------
DATE         CATEGORY
2016-04-20   sport
2016-04-20   bar
2016-04-29   sport
```

the only way I know how to group is, for example:

```
SELECT DATE, CATEGORY
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY CATEGORY
```

but since this code doesn't involve the date-factor it's not what I'm after and I don't know how to say something like

```
SELECT DATE, CATEGORY
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY CATEGORY
when date == date... yadayada
```

Is there any way to do this in sql or do I need to group it by php or what do you say?

Comment: `GROUP BY date, category` in your first query.

Comment: sometime it's just too simple....... *facepalm.... thank you! @GordonLinoff

Comment: In fact, your initial query is syntactically incorrect. Every other RDMS SQL dialect would have failed on that query. MySQL allows it because you do not have ANSI mode on with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_ON` (which is default as of MySQL 5.7). IHO a true disservice for new SQL users.